# What is the most performant way to make a text animation for each letter

Tags: javascript, css, animation

As far as I know "transform" is not the most performant property to animate. If I want to achieve a text-split animation transforming all letters of a block - eg. for revealing text on scroll - what would be the most performant way to do that?

Here is my approach:
https://codepen.io/markusreis/pen/mdJgzOj

- Split the text into spans

```js
const split = (e) => {
  e = document.querySelector( e );
  e.innerHTML = e.innerText.split('').map( l => `<span data-letter="${l}">${l}</span>`).join('')
}
```

- Animate each span

```css
.block {
  
  span[data-letter] {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    &:before {
      color: black;
      content: attr(data-letter);
      position: absolute;
      transform: skewX(-15deg) skewY(15deg) translateY(100%);
      transition: transform .6s cubic-bezier(0.25,0,0.25,1);
    }
    @for $i from 1 through 100 {
      &:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
        &:before {
          transition-delay: #{$i * 15}ms;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  &:hover {
    span[data-letter] {
      &:before {
        transform: skewX(0) skewY(0) translateY(0);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But especially when having more or longer text blocks the animation will not be that fluent any more.

Any suggestions on how to improve the effect? I mean... some websites achieve a lot of transform animations with ease and others are very laggy. So there must be a better technique?

Comment: Re: _"As far as I know "transform" is not the most performant property to animate"_ Out of curiosity, do you have a source for this,please? Thanks.